# How to emit events from component to main instance usint $emit or vuex

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vuex

I want to use my main vuejs instance to manage sockets.io connection and events. I have this code that works, but I have some problems to pass events from component to parent instance. The code is inside a chrome extension that use vuex, but I'm not familiar with vuex at the moment. How I can pass events between my main instance and child component? Someone has suggested me to use vuex, but it's divided in three files and I'm not able to understand for now how to obtain what I want.

```js
<script>
  // child component 
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        isRegistered: false,
        isConnected: false
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$on('connected', function(event) {
        console.log(event)
      })
    },
    methods: {
      initRoom() {
        console.log('clicked!')
        this.$emit('openConnection')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```js
// main instance
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import store from '../store'
import router from './router'
import VueSocketIOExt from 'vue-socket.io-extended';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('https://lost-conn.herokuapp.com', {
  autoConnect: false
});

Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, socket, { store });

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
  mounted() {
    this.$on('openConnection', function() {
      socket.open()
      alert('k')
    })
  },
  data: {
    isRegistered: false,
    isConnected: false,
    message: ''
  },
  sockets: {
    connect() {
      console.log('socket connected')
      this.$emit('connected', 'socket connected')
    },
  },
  methods: {}
})
```

Comment: In my card game, I instanciate a class `ApiSocketGame` in my main, I'm giving to it callbacks for alls event to update my properties, this class is used by all of my components (Lobby, room, game), they call his methods to emit, then when there have event, my properties are updated by vue reactivity. I don't know if it's best way but this work fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can try vuex but it seems kind of heavy if all you want is a basic event listener. One option might be to go with the eventBus route and set up an emitter and a listener event. in main.js you can add

```
export const eventBus = new Vue()
```

Then in your code you could swap `this.$emit('connected', 'socket connected')`

with `eventBus.$emit('connected', true_or_any_other_value_here)`

Then in your component that you're listening for the event. Import eventBus from main.js and add:

```
data: ( => ({ bus: eventBus }),

created() {
    this.bus.$on('connected', ($event) => myCallbackFunction($event) )
},
```

I think this should do the trick, I haven't yet tried the callback function and passing data as I usually do my check on the front end but if there is data object you need to store please specify and I might be able to help you through using vuex.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've read the vue docs and I wasn't able to find detailed instruction about events. Someone in the vue chat told me that the event bus isn't the best way to emit events, butin my case, for a small app will work fine. I was wondering if I can use vuex, but the vue cli divided vuex in three files and for now it's too difficult for me to make things working from separate files.

Comment: Yeah, it can be a little heavy if all you need is an event emitter, and in a chrome extension you should also have access to local storage to store small bits of information. For a full app I would recommend vuex but this should get you most if not all of the way there. Let me know, good luck!

Comment: I'm implementing the event bus, but I have a little problem, I have added the bus inside the main js file of the extension but this will not work,  the extension will open a new tab where all the app is running and the component isn't able to find the exported value. Any suggestion?